# ¿qué directiva de laravel me permite incluir cuantas veces quiera determinado código de blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Tengo una vista de blade en donde uso el siguiente código:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h3>Listado de tareas por hacer...<h3>
        @foreach ($misTareas as $tarea)
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 d-flex my-card-rounded">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <span class="font-weight-bold">Id</span>
                        <span>{{ $tarea->id }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <span class="font-weight-bold">Titulo</span>
                        <span>{{ $tarea->title }}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <span class="font-weight-bold">Usuario creó</span>
                        <span>{{ $tarea->user_create }}</span>
                    </div><div class="d-flex">
                        <span class="font-weight-bold">Usuario asignado</span>
                        <span>{{ $tarea->user_assigned }}</span>
                    </div><div class="d-flex">
                        <span class="font-weight-bold">Descripción</span>
                        <span>{{ $tarea->description }}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
                    <h4>Registro de actividad<h4>
                
                    @foreach($tarea->activity_register as $itemActivity)
                        <div class="row m-0">
                            <div class="col-md-4>
                                <span class="font-weight-bold">Acción: {{ $itemActivity->detail }}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4>
                                <span class="font-weight-bold">Realizado el: {{ $itemActivity->created_at }}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4>
                                <span class="font-weight-bold">Realizado por: {{ $itemActivity->user_activity_create }}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    @endforeach
                
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

El cual uso en varias partes de mi vista blade, exactamente igual, me gustaría saber qué directiva de blade podría evitarme la repetición de este mismo código, de manera que yo crease una nueva vista con este template y la pudiese usar cuantas veces quisiera en cualquier parte de mi vista principal. Además de saber cómo pasar el parámetro que necesito usar allí el cual sería la variable **$misTareas** y que recorro en el foreach que se muestra.

Answer (score 0):

Hallé la directiva que lo realiza, solo conocía de @extends pero la que me sirvió en este caso es `@include('modules.todos.todos_list')`, en donde llamo a la vista que ya contiene el código que se repetía y por el parámetro que debía pasarle, no hay problema ya que al hacer el include es como si mi template "todos_list" se encontrase dentro de mi vista principal.

```
<div>
     @include('modules.todos.todos_list')
</div>
```

Otra sección de mi vista principal:

```
<div>
     @include('modules.todos.todos_list')
</div>
```